Why Windows is not able to create virtual memory on a secondary SSD?
Currently I have two SSD installed on my laptop. C and E drive are on the primary drive. D and F are on the secondary drive. The primary drive comes stock with the laptop. The secondary drive is newly installed onto the M2 slot originally for the 4G WAN module.
I'm running out of space on the C drive so I'm trying to relocate the page file to the secondary drive. But whenever I set the page file size on C to 0, and set a valid size on D or F, the system would have difficulty booting up, and will show a dialog, telling me that my configuration is invalid, and a temporary page file is created so that the system can boot.
This picture shows the status after such a boot. You can see on the C drive, even though the size is set to None, the actual size is 3584MB. At the same time, F was set to 24000MB firm but have actually no page file at all.

It seems like Windows isn't able to create a page file on any of the partitions on the secondary drive during early boot, and isn't trying to create one after boot. I thought I could leave a small page file on my C drive to boot the system and hope that Windows would use the page file on the F drive when needed. But I was wrong. They system would hang and start to low-memory-kill processes after it run out of page file space on the C drive.
What am I doing wrong here?
The RAM size of this computer is very large, relative to the C drive (24GB vs 120GB), so moving the page file out of C drive really helps both sides: page file could be bigger and C has more free space.

Instead of setting it to Zero, have you tried setting it a few MBS, and see if the currently allocated changes?

@AshishMohta Yes I tried. I tried to set C drive to 800MB and F to any value, and the system will show it has allocated 800MB. And I sometimes run out of swap space (800MB is too small). It seems like committed memory must be lower than RAM+SWAP. The over-commit ratio of my usage pattern (web and office) is about 2:1, so, in order not to run out of swap before running out of RAM, the swap should be same as RAM (working set + over-commit = RAM + SWAP)

Fix: “Windows created a temporary paging file” message at startup

Windows may keep creating a temporary paging file on the OS volume because of the PagefileOnOsVolume registry setting.
When BitLocker is enabled on the computer, it creates the
“PagefileOnOsVolume” registry value and sets its data to “1”. This
forces Windows to create pagefile.sys on the OS partition, ignoring
your custom settings in the “Performance Options” dialog.
BitLocker enables the registry setting to help protect confidential
data in a page file.

BitLocker Drive Encryption (BDE) enables the PagefileOnOSVolume registry setting on Windows

The Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista
memory-management system includes a feature that automatically manages
the system pagefile. The memory-management system typically puts the
pagefile on the same volume as the operating system (OS). However, if
this volume does not have sufficient space, the pagefile may be
relocated to another local volume on which more disk space is
available. This relocation may cause data-confidentiality issues when
BDE is used to protect the OS volume. Specifically, information may be
disclosed if the pagefile's new location is on a volume that is not
encrypted by BDE.
To reduce this threat, BDE automatically creates the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PagefileOnOsVolume

This subkey lets you
direct the memory-management system to put the pagefile only on the
BDE-protected OS volume. Specifically, if you set this subkey to a
value of 1, the OS volume is the only volume that the Session
Management Sub System (SMSS) will consider as a location for the
pagefile. If there is insufficient space on the OS volume, SMSS will
create a smaller pagefile on this volume.

When I tried to relocate the page file, I though about the security issues. So I did turn on Bitlocker on the secondary drive. I specifically tried it with both Bitlocker on AND off and saw no difference. The full story seems more convolved than that.
In short, after Vista, size of the page file becomes dynamic. Page file grow and shrink on demand and can spill to another partition if there's not enough space in the OS partition. When Bitlocker is enabled, in order to not spill the page file to an unencrypted drive, Bitlocker would pin the page file to the OS partition. And there's a side effect that, the user is also not able to relocate the page file else where, either, even to a known encrypted drive.
Be aware of the security issues here. It is highly recommended that the page file stays on an encrypted drive. If you want to move the page file on a different location, make sure the target location is encrypted.


I am confused. I thought you were running Windows 11?

@Ramhound They are the same
